# How can I inject a parameterized type with @Context in Jersey?

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

I have an InjectableProvider written in the style of [Coda Hale's AbstractInjectableProvider](http://codahale.com/what-makes-jersey-interesting-injection-providers/) which provides an Id:

```
@Override
public Id<User> getValue(HttpContext httpContext) {
  return new Id<User>(1234);
}
```

This code in my resource works:

```
@GET
@Produces( { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
@Path("accounts")
public AccountsSummary getAccounts(@Context Id userId) {
  return accountsSummaryFromUserId(userId);
}
```

When I add the type parameter like this:

```
public AccountsSummary getAccounts(@Context Id<User> userId) {
```

I get an error on startup:

```
SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public com.example.AccountsSummary com.example.ExperimentApi.getAccounts(com.example.Id) at parameter at index 0
SEVERE: Method, public com.example.AccountsSummary com.example.ExperimentApi.getAccounts(com.example.Id), annotated with GET of resource, class com.example.ExperimentApi, is not recognized as valid resource method.
```

At some point, I can anticipate that I might need to inject other types of Ids or other parameterized classes. How can I make @Context aware of generics? Do I need to do something related to making getInjectable use Parameter rather than Type?

Comment: I don't believe this is possible. Jersey must use some kind of Resolver strategy to find the object to inject into your method at runtime. Because of type erasure, it wouldn't be able to figure out the generic type.

Comment: Why `@Context` instead of `@Inject`?

Comment: Sotirios: Guice supports injecting by parameterized type. Type erasure applies to the objects.